# Inconsistent results in Google Sheets macros?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have the following spreadsheet (and this is it's ideal beginning state):

[image]

When you enter a number in the yellow field (B55), C55 and D55 are calculated (based on other stuff not relevant to the problem).

Here's what I need a macro to do: (1) Copy B58, and paste the value ("1") in B55. This will change the values of C55 and D55.(2) Copy C55, paste the value in C58. (3) Copy D55, paste the value in D58. (4) Repeat steps 1-4, but this time with row 59. (5) Repeat, but with row 60. (6) Etc.

So if the script only ran once (on B58), it should look like ...

[image]

If the script runs with 4 rows of year data (B58-B61), and this is what the script code below should do, the output SHOULD look like this:

[image]

Really it should run for 20 iterations, with a final value of "100" years. But for brevity and to illustrate the problem, I stopped at "15". But let's say, for example, I enter 100 in the yellow field, I get ...

[image]

If I were run the script at this point, however, I get ...

[image]

See how they are all the same value? The macro I recorded is copying the last entry in C55 and D55, instead of the calculated values for 1, then 5, then 10, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the script it created:

```js
function TEST1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  spreadsheet.getRange('B55').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B58').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C58').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D58').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  spreadsheet.getRange('B55').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B59').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C59').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D59').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  spreadsheet.getRange('B55').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B60').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C60').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D60').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  spreadsheet.getRange('B55').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B61').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C61').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D61').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Note: This is a simplification of a larger requirement. A macro is necessary, I can't turn the table into multiple formulas.

Comment: Your script runs the following flow. 1. Cells B58, C55 and D55 are copied to B55, C58 and D58, respectively. 2. Cells B59, C55 and D55 are copied to B55, C59 and D59, respectively. 3. Cells B60, C55 and D55 are copied to B55, C60 and D60, respectively. 4. Cells B61, C55 and D55 are copied to B55, C61 and D61, respectively.

Comment: By above flow, when the script is run after 100, 281,259 and 256,756 were put to the cells B55, C55 and D55, respectively, the result will be the same with your question. But I'm not sure about the reason that 201,820 and 172,677 are changed to 281,259 and 256,756 in your bottom image. Can you explain about this? And in order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the input and output you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike , thank you for the input. I've rewritten the question to be a little more clear. Basically it just seems like the calculations in C55 and D55 are not being copied when the value in B55 is updated by the script.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. I proposed an answer for achieving your goal. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to copy `B58` to `B55`. At this time, `C55` and `D55` are calculated. You want to copy the calculated values of `C55:D55` to `C58:D58`.

  - You want to run this flow for each row.
- You want to achieve this by modifying your script.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Modification point:

- In your case, in order to calculate the values, please use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`. After `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` was run, the calculated values are copied.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script is modified. Please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function TEST1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  spreadsheet.getRange('B55').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B58').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Added
  spreadsheet.getRange('C58').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D58').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  spreadsheet.getRange('B55').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B59').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Added
  spreadsheet.getRange('C59').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D59').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  spreadsheet.getRange('B55').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B60').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Added
  spreadsheet.getRange('C60').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D60').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  spreadsheet.getRange('B55').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B61').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Added
  spreadsheet.getRange('C61').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D61').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D55').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the start row and end row you want to retrieve are declared, and the values are copied in the for loop. Please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function TEST1() {
  var startRow = 58; // Please set the start row. In this case, it's row 58.
  var endRow = 61; // Please set the start row. In this case, it's row 61.

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  for (var row = startRow; row <= endRow; row++) {
    spreadsheet.getRange("B" + row).copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange("B55"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    spreadsheet.getRange("C55:D55").copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange("C" + row + ":D" + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  }
}
```

### Reference:

- [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

Comment: Oh man. You're obviously crazy smart, but I think there's a basic misunderstanding. Probably my fault for not being clear enough. Here's what I need the macro to do: (1) Copy B58, paste value in B55. This will change C55 and D55.(2) Copy C55, paste value in C58. (3) Copy D55, paste value in D58. (4) Repeat steps 1-4, but this time with row 59. (5) Again, but with row 60. That's what the script should do. Why isn't it working?

Comment: @neokio Thank you for replying. I could notice that I misunderstood your goal. I have to apologize. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: I've learned so much from your answers! Thank you for your brilliance, and for taking the time to help. It's deeply appreciated.

Comment: @neokio Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.